# How to combine all the queued jobs(gerrit changes) and run as a single job in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins is configured with gerrit plug-in and build the code per each gerrit change when its merged. While my build is taking place there will be some more gerrits merged and those jobs will be in queue to build. My question is how to combine all those queued jobs and run as a single job once the current job is completed. Either way how to get those all latest merged change list and run in a single job next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a master job and make that job to run other jobs by setting Post-build Actions and set deploy other projects by giving names of jobs which you want to deploy.